# How to implement API-based login between two Laravel applications

Tags: php, laravel

Please I'm facing an issue while attempting to implement API-based login functionality between two Laravel applications, let's call them Application A and Application B. I need assistance in achieving this. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- I have two separate Laravel applications, Application A and
  Application B.

  I want to enable users to log into Application B from Application A
  using an API.

  Essentially, when a user logs into Application A, I want to
  authenticate their credentials against Application B's user system
  and log them in.

I'm looking for guidance on how to set up the necessary API endpoints and handle the authentication process between the two applications.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance, guidance, or sample code that can help me achieve this API-based login functionality between the two Laravel applications. Thank you in advance for your help!

**APPLICATION A** - ROUTE

```
Route::post('/api-login', function(){

$data = [
    'email' => request('email'),
    'role' => "Administrator",
    'password' => "openme23"
];

$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/from-pos';
$response = Http::retry(3, 2000)->post($url, $data);

return $response;

})->name('ApiLogin');
```

**APPLICATION B - api.php**

```
$rules = array(
    'email' => 'email|required|max:300',
    'role' => 'required|max:300',
);


$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return $validator->errors();
}

$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

if (request('role') == "Administrator") {
    if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response([
            'status' => 419,
            'Message' => "Sorry! unauthorized user"
        ]);
    }


    $user = Auth::user();
    $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('token', $token);

    
}else{
    return response([
        'status' => 419,
        'Message' => "Sorry! unauthorized user"
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Do the users have the same credentials in both applications? If not, how should A know what to log in with when calling B? Also...broader design question: why not just an established SSO design, where both applications share the same authentication provider?

Comment: Yes, same login credentials.

Comment: Then really you just should set up some SSO archicture, that's the sane way to do it